# Sorting python list based on elements occurrence using single loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a problem, to sort the python list based on occurrence of elements.

for example:

```
#input list: 
l = [5,5,5,2,2,4,4,4,4,1]

#output list 
[4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 1]
```

I am able to solve the problem but i have used 3 loops, can anybody help me to do this in some pythonic way using a single loop. if you want i can share my solution. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `collections.Counter` to count elements, then sort by that

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = [5,5,5,2,2,4,4,4,4,1]
>>> c = Counter(l)
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda i: c[i], reverse=True)
[4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 1]
```

Comment: No need to import collections.Counter : `sorted(l, key = lambda x: l.count(x), reverse=True)`

Comment: @May.D Repeated calls to `list.count` are terrible. It is much better to collect all counts in one iteration.